# jquery triggered after validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, checkbox

i am using laravel 5.3 with laravelcollective/html 5.2..
i made a checkbox that if that checked, a hidden input will come out and if i uncheck it the input will be hidden.. and after the validation request error from laravel the checkbox remain checked but the hidden input didnt show up.. please i need help.. thanks..

my checkbox html:

```
<label>
{!! Form::checkbox('penerima_beda', '1', null, ['id' => 'penerima_beda']) !!}Penerima Berbeda
</label>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
$("#penerima_beda").click(function() {
        if(this.checked){
            $("#panel_penerima").css("display", "block");
            $("#nama_penerima").attr("required", "required");
            $("#no_telp_penerima").attr("required", "required");
            $("#alamat_penerima").attr("required", "required");
            //console.log(this);
        }else if(!this.checked){
            $("#panel_penerima").css("display", "none");
            $("#nama_penerima").removeAttr("required");
            $("#no_telp_penerima").removeAttr("required");
            $("#alamat_penerima").removeAttr("required");
        }
    });
```

Comment: is your input field inside a separate div? share the code for the input section which has to be showed/hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an check clause on document load to show the hidden input field

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Show the input if the checkbox is checked
    if ($("#penerima_beda").is(":checked")) {
        $("#panel_penerima").css("display", "block");
        $("#nama_penerima").attr("required", "required");
        $("#no_telp_penerima").attr("required", "required");
        $("#alamat_penerima").attr("required", "required");
    }

    // This works only on click event
    $("#penerima_beda").click(function() {
        if(this.checked){
            $("#panel_penerima").css("display", "block");
            $("#nama_penerima").attr("required", "required");
            $("#no_telp_penerima").attr("required", "required");
            $("#alamat_penerima").attr("required", "required");
        }else if(!this.checked){
            $("#panel_penerima").css("display", "none");
            $("#nama_penerima").removeAttr("required");
            $("#no_telp_penerima").removeAttr("required");
            $("#alamat_penerima").removeAttr("required");
        }
    });

});
```